# How to Integrate Waze Traffic Data into Website?

Tags: java, jquery, parsing

Could anyone show me a way on how to integrate the traffic info app Waze into the website?

I have looked up the previous post but somehow there is no answer to it.

Waze is an application, which offers an actual traffic information. There is also a livemap Waze livemap - where are marks as you can see.

So, I found some site - [egaraz](http://www.egaraz.cz/traffic) and I'm really curious how did they get the data from Waze.

Programming is not my main field but a could still understand some basic php coding.

Could someone suggest me a working solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

a while ago i wrote this project:

https://github.com/Nimrod007/waze-api

you can run this api and get:

- get address list from free text
- get routes by address (text)
- get routes by coordinates
- get traffic notification
- get navigation instructions

link to full docs:

http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Nimrod007/waze-api/blob/master/docs.html

Comment: Looks like the API is no longer available. Does anyone know an alternative? Would be really useful to pull traffic data from Waze based on location.

Answer (score 0):

After googling I found that WAZE has an API for developers which you can use. They have given sample code only for android and ios. I am not sure about php. Check this link from waze developer - http://www.waze.com/dev/documentation/

Comment: They probably don't let apps gather data freely (e.g. like twitter) because it creates extra queries over their infrastructure and their data is their main resource to generate revenue.

They probably limits the way we can get and display their data. Maybe OP needs to be a reporting user to get traffic information in their current location. Agree about checking the API and coming back with more specific questions.